# Pandas - Lists as index values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I understand that Pandas **Index** values must be **immutable**/hashable. However, on running the following code - I was surprised to see that the list was allowed as an index value.

```
import pandas as pd

obj = pd.Series([4,7,5,23,3], index = [2,'A', 2+3j, (3,7), [1,2]], name = 'Trial')
print(obj)

print(type(obj))
```

Output:

```
2          4
A          7
(2+3j)     5
(3, 7)    23
[1, 2]     3
Name: Trial, dtype: int64

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

In the past, I have experimented with trying to put an unhashable type as an index value and as expected - was not allowed to.

Is there something I am missing in this piece of code? Have there been changes to the library?

Of course, while trying to subscript the value at that index using obj[[1,2]], I get the 'unhashable type - list' error as expected. But as far as I recall, in the past, I was never allowed to use a list as the index value in the first place.

Thanks in advance for any help/explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> In the past, I have experimented with trying to put an unhashable type as an index value and as expected - was not allowed to.

Are you sure?

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

print(pd.__version__)  # 0.24.2
print(sys.version)  # '2.7.18 (default, Jan 23 2023, 08:22:06) \n[GCC 12.2.0]'

obj = pd.Series([4,7,5,23,3], index = [2,'A', 2+3j, (3,7), [1,2]], name = 'Trial')
print(obj[[1,2]])

# Output  (which is wrong but it works)
A         7
(2+3j)    5
Name: Trial, dtype: int64
```

It also works for python==3.8.10 and pandas==1.0.5.

Comment: Ok. I am not 100% sure ....but now it is clear that it works. 

In the example of subscription you have given - it is getting the output as if one was using index number subscription. 

Also, if this IS being allowed as an Index value - doesnt it break the whole idea of the label to value intrinsic pairing (like a key:value pair in a dictionary, keys must be immutable). Whats going on here? 

Any help would be appreciated.